# Extract number from format string in R

Tags: r, string

Let's say I have a bunch of strings given in the format: `#%d-%d-%d`.

For example,

```
#50-69-1
#49-69-2
...
```

How can I extract the first number for every string without brute force approach by loop?

For the example above I want to get:

```
50
49
...
```

Comment: Do you have `#` in the strings or is just a comment character?

Comment: @akrun, I have it in the strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `stri_extract` function.

```
> library(stringi)
> x <- "#50-69-1"
> stri_extract(x, regex="\\d+")
[1] "50"
> regmatches(x, regexpr("\\d+", x))
[1] "50"
```

**OR**

```
> gsub("^\\D*|-.*", "", "#49-69-1")
[1] "49"
> gsub("^#|-.*", "", "#49-69-1")
[1] "49"
```

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
sub('^#(\\d+)-.*', '\\1', str1)
#[1] "50" "49"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c('#50-69-1', '#49-69-2')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
x <- c("50-69-1","49-69-2")
```

You can use

```
substring(x,1,2)
> [1] "50" "49"
```